# STM32F429 SPI issue

Tags: stm32, spi, stm32f4

I am trying to get SPI working on STM322F429-disco board. Here is the setup:

1. SPI2 is setup as a master with Soft NSS and SSOE enabled. GPIOG Pin11 is being used manually for Chip select.

   2. SPI4 is setup as a Slave with SSM and SSI bits set.

Following is the setup code:

```
SPI_InitTypeDef SPI_struct;
SPI_InitTypeDef SPI_struct1;
void SPI_Config_Master()
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef Init_struct;
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_SPI2,ENABLE);
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB,ENABLE);

    GPIO_DeInit(GPIOB);

    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB,GPIO_PinSource13,GPIO_AF_SPI2);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB,GPIO_PinSource14,GPIO_AF_SPI2);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB,GPIO_PinSource15,GPIO_AF_SPI2);

    Init_struct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
    Init_struct.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    Init_struct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    Init_struct.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_DOWN;

    Init_struct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_13;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB,&Init_struct);

    Init_struct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_14;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB,&Init_struct);

    Init_struct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_15;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB,&Init_struct);

    //Init_struct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_15;
    //GPIO_Init(GPIOB,&Init_struct);

    SPI_I2S_DeInit(SPI2);


    SPI_struct.SPI_Direction = SPI_Direction_2Lines_FullDuplex;
    SPI_struct.SPI_DataSize = SPI_DataSize_16b;
    SPI_struct.SPI_CPOL = SPI_CPOL_High;
    SPI_struct.SPI_CPHA = SPI_CPHA_2Edge;
    SPI_struct.SPI_NSS = SPI_NSS_Soft;
    SPI_struct.SPI_BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BaudRatePrescaler_64;
    SPI_struct.SPI_FirstBit = SPI_FirstBit_MSB;
    SPI_struct.SPI_CRCPolynomial = 7;
    SPI_struct.SPI_Mode = SPI_Mode_Master;
}

void SPI_Config_Slave()
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef Init_struct;
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_SPI4,ENABLE);
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOE,ENABLE);

    GPIO_DeInit(GPIOE);

    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE,GPIO_PinSource4,GPIO_AF_SPI4);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE,GPIO_PinSource5,GPIO_AF_SPI4);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE,GPIO_PinSource6,GPIO_AF_SPI4);

    Init_struct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
    Init_struct.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    Init_struct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    Init_struct.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_DOWN;


    Init_struct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_4;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOE,&Init_struct);

    Init_struct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_5;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOE,&Init_struct);

    Init_struct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_6;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOE,&Init_struct);

    SPI_I2S_DeInit(SPI4);


    SPI_struct1.SPI_Direction = SPI_Direction_2Lines_FullDuplex;
    SPI_struct1.SPI_DataSize = SPI_DataSize_16b;
    SPI_struct1.SPI_CPOL = SPI_CPOL_High;
    SPI_struct1.SPI_CPHA = SPI_CPHA_2Edge;
    SPI_struct1.SPI_NSS = SPI_NSS_Soft;
    SPI_struct1.SPI_BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BaudRatePrescaler_64;
    SPI_struct1.SPI_FirstBit = SPI_FirstBit_MSB;
    SPI_struct1.SPI_CRCPolynomial = 7;
    SPI_struct1.SPI_Mode = SPI_Mode_Slave;
}

int main()
{

  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOG, ENABLE);
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitDef;
  GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_Mode=GPIO_Mode_OUT;
  GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_Speed=GPIO_Fast_Speed;
  GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_OType=GPIO_OType_PP;
  GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_PuPd=GPIO_PuPd_UP;
  GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_11;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOG, &GPIO_InitDef);

  SPI_Config_Master();
  SPI_Config_Slave();

SPI_Init(SPI2,&SPI_struct);
SPI2->CR2 |= (uint16_t)SPI_CR2_SSOE;
SPI2->CR1 &= (uint16_t)(~SPI_CR1_SSI);
SPI_Cmd(SPI2,ENABLE);

SPI_Init(SPI4,&SPI_struct1);
SPI_Cmd(SPI4,ENABLE);

uint16_t temp[4]={0};

while(1) {

temp[0]=((0x56 << 8) | 0x00);
temp[1]=((0x56 << 8) | 0x00);
temp[2]=((0x56 << 8) | 0x00);
temp[3]=((0x56 << 8) | 0x00);

GPIOG->ODR &= ~GPIO_Pin_11;

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        while((SPI2->SR & SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE)!=SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE);
        SPI_I2S_SendData(SPI2,temp[i]);
        while((SPI4->SR & SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE) != SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE);
        temp[i]= SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI4);
    }

   GPIOG->ODR |= GPIO_Pin_11;

}

}
```

Here are the issues i'm having with this code.

1) SPI2 peripheral registers do not get set after the respective setup code.[image]

2) When i use SPI4 as master and other external spi device as a slave. I get no signals on scope.

Any help in finding the solution?

Comment: Your `SPI_Struct` & `SPI_Struct1` are never initialized. You're not calling your `SPI_Config_Master()` or `SPI_Config_Slave()`.

Comment: @brhans: sorry i was copy pasting the code and forgot to include that part. I am initializing it. Thank you for noticing

Comment: First try running one of the F429 Discovery SPI examples *verbatim and unmodified*.  Verify that works.  Then think about how your code is different.